# Is energy conserved under perturbation (Classical System)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, orbital-motion, perturbation-theory

Surprisingly, I don't see this question on here, so here goes.

If I have a classical system and perturbation is applied is the energy before and after equal. I want to say no. However, I am not sure.

For a concrete example, consider a circular particle in orbit with radius $r_0$. The particle is then perturbed radially

(Requested edit) s.t. $r_0 \rightarrow r_0 + \epsilon$. Therefore, the Euler-Lagrange of r goes to $\ddot{\epsilon} = (r_0+\epsilon)\dot{\phi}_0^2 + \frac{\alpha}{(r_0 +\epsilon)^2}$. (Here, potential is $\frac{\alpha}{r}$). After approximating and solving we find that particle begins to oscillate radially while following the original orbit.

My question is $E_i=E_f$ ?

Comment: It's not clear what it is that you have in mind when you use the expression 'apply a perturbation'. You write that you expect that after what refer to as 'a perturbation is applied: "[...] the particle begins to oscillate radially while following the original orbit." You appear to expect a superposition of two motions: a radial oscillation *and* the original orbit. For the radial oscillation that you expect, do you expect that oscillation to have a regular period, and if so, what duration do you expect? This is for the purpose of finding what you mean by 'apply a perturbation'.

Comment: @Cleonis I have updated the question specifying what I mean by radial perturbation and why it follows that r(t) will oscillate. Also, specified circular orbital which should have included/meant to specify.

Comment: I recommend that you submit this question on a threaded forum, such as physicsforums. The reason: in physics the word 'perturbation' is used for a range of things. Example: in celestial mechanics both a single event and ongoing periodic effect are referred to as 'perturbation'. Specific examples: the impact of the NASA DART mission caused a permanent change in the orbit of the asteroid Dimorphos. The orbit of the planet Mercury can be thought of as a superposition of a Kepler orbit and ongoing perturbation by the other planets in the solar system. It's not clear which meaning you have in mind.

Comment: @Cleonis all set thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We typically treat a perturbed and an unperturbed system as different systems. Meaning the perturbed and unperturbed system evolve according to the same laws of physics, but have different initial or boundary conditions.

As such, if energy is conserved for the perturbed system it is conserved for the unperturbed system. But the energy need not be the same for the perturbed vs unperturbed systems. One does not evolve into the other according to the laws of physics.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That is exactly what I was wondering, and makes total sense!

Comment: @EricH Note that we also very often consider systems with *time-dependent* perturbations which may be non-existent or negligible for some time and then smoothly (or abruptly) "turn on". In such cases, whether total energy is conserved depends on the nature of the perturbation and on how exactly it is turned on.